# How to use TI Sensortag on Windows Desktop with USB 4.0 BLE Dongle

Tags: bluetooth, desktop-application

I have an Asus USB-BT400 Bluetooth Dongle, it works with BLE devices. I also have an TI Sensortag, i installed the drivers and software and I can connect my PC to the sensortag (using windows 7 or windows 8.1 in VM, both works).
Windows doesn't find drivers for the sensors (I think 8 in total) so I would like to know how I can communicate to them. I already exposed a COM port for the bluetooth device (that's possible via Bluetooth settings). I tried the BLE device monitor, where the COM port shows up, but it gives an error (no response from BLE host at port COM3). I also tried the windows Desktop app (win8), which doesn't work either.

I would be glad for any solutions, resources and hints which do not require me to buy the Dongle from TI website for ~50$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it works under anything less than Win 8.1 as the OS must have the BLE Profile drivers.
Running VM is not going to help, as you need those drivers at the base OS level.

Comment: Thanks, I would upvote you, but Stackoverflow has strange rules. I will upvote you as soon as I have 15 reputation